# How would you remap the meta key on emacs?

Tags: keyboard, emacs, exceed

I am using Emacs-24.2. I start it from a linux server and display it on my Exceed server, on my WindowsXP desktop.

I have to type in the ESC key on my keyboard to get the META modifier.

What is the easiest way to fix this mapping please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure exceed to send meta to X-windows. See http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about178796.html and the Exceed user manual about keyboard input.

Comment: Yes, found the correct option. From French: in the "mouse, keyboard and opther input devices" panel, I assigned the Alt key to X instead of trying to share it with windows.